# is concat faster or slower than push

Tags: javascript, performance

For this code I want to know in javascript what is the best approach?

```
var output = foo +";"+bar;
```

or

```
var output = new Array(foo,bar).join(";");
```

Comment: Are you planning to do this 10,000 times in a row? If you don't, it likely won't matter.

Comment: yes I do for 100000times

Comment: I don't know what to make of these questions. You could try them both in your app. If there's no visible difference, it doesn't matter which you use. If there is a visible difference, you already know the answer.

Comment: @Pekka in my opinion it matters. Recently I've made a blog post (http://blog.mgechev.com/?p=231) for a performance optimization which was negligible for some but when you're creating software for high traffic web site the difference when using optimized solutions is really greatly noticeable.

Comment: @MinkoGechev Noticeable to who? JS is client side. Even if the combined performance loss of every user were huge, neither the server nor an individual user see any difference.

Comment: @Juhana we're far away from the times when JavaScript was only client-side. I think you should read more about that here: http://nodejs.org/

Comment: @MinkoGechev nothing here suggests that we're talking about node.js.

Comment: @Juhana and also nothing suggests that we don't...The question was about JavaScript.

Comment: @MinkoGechev then why is your answer only about browser engines :)

Comment: @Juhana Nodejs uses V8 engine. I said JS engine, not browser engine :-)

Comment: According to this [Google dev doc](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript), IE has had memory leak issues with its string concatenation, and suggests using `.join()` to avoid them.

Comment: @MinkoGechev if it's not tagged with a server-side tag, chances are exceedingly great that it's about the browser. You're totally right (and impressive blog posts!), but people often ask about performance  comparisons while they are calling the function only a couple of times. In those scenarios, I'm sure you agree, the couple of microseconds' difference will be negligible and the right choice is to pick the option that is easiest to read. Discussing performance differences then quickly becomes counterproductive.

Comment: @IHateLazy nice link! Pekka thanks about the blog post! dystroy was right about the "more readable approach" but in my opinion it's good to know the fastest alternative (although the readability is almost always more important).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't really matter.

There were blogs promoting the first one or the second one, depending on their benchmarks.

But the truth is that javascript engines are heavily optimized and changing, so you won't find a big reproducible and cross-browser difference.

Choose the most readable. Generally it's the first one.

If you really do a loop with 10000 times this push, benchmark it on your customer browsers in your real code, and choose the best but only if there is a significative difference. Don't forget that javascript is fast.

Answer (score 1):

There are many test cases in http://jsperf.com/ (for example http://jsperf.com/joint-vs-concat). There you can check which is slower.
In my experience depends on the user's browser (to be more exact - JS engine).

Answer (score 0):

According to me String concatenation is faster  then array joins .  saw these test cases

http://jsperf.com/array-join-vs-string-connect
http://jsperf.com/join-concat/2